# Pooling CloseableHttpClient without caching

Tags: apache, cookies, configuration, httpclient

I used singleTone  configuration to manage pooled http client

```
  public CloseableHttpClient getCloseableHttpClient() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal(100);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
    .build();

    return HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig)
        .build();
  }
```

The problem is it uses cookies.

Can I switch off ones?

If I'm using client second time for same URL, it has CookieStore with nonEmpty cookie elements.